# Why ambiguous grammars are allowed for operator precedence parser?

Tags: parsers, ambiguity

I am aware of what is ambiguity, and why is it necessary to eliminate ambiguity in compilers in a certain context, but how can we allow ambiguity for operator precedence parser? Say I have a set of operations like a-b-c now if we operate it with two different parse trees, say one like (a-b)-c and other like a-(b-c)
there meaning changes..
So how can we allow ambiguous grammar in operator precedence parser? shouldn't it be the opposite?

Comment: An operator precedence parser knows how to resolve this ambiguity, in this case by associating subtraction to the left.

Comment: "Precedence" includes information about "rank" AND associativity (left or right) of the operation

Answer (score 3):

An operator precedence parser usually has no ambiguity at all. However, the evaluation order is not determined by the parse tree, but by the operator precedences and associativities.

As a practical example, the Swift language doesn't *define* operator precedence or associativity in the language. It doesn't even define operators, except that the scanner knows which sequences of letters could be operators. The actual operators and precedence / associativity are define by the programmer, or as part of the standard library. As a result, a+b*c>d/e produces a parse tree that just consists of the five operands and four potential operators. The parse *is* unique, but doesn't tell how the expression should be evaluated.

The next phase checks that all the four potential operators *are* indeed operators. Then the priorities and associativity of the operators, as defined by the programmer or standard library, are examined. * and / have highest priority, + has lower, and > has even lower priority. If you had a-b-c, then the two operators have the same precedence, and both are left-associative, so the order is also clear. If you had two or more consecutive operators with same priority and different associativity, or with no associativity, that would be an error.

You couldn't define a grammar to handle operators, because their precedence and associativity are not even known when you start compiling.